# Finding a minimum stops along a route with a car that has unlimited tank

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you want to go to a place that is D miles away, and you have a car that has unlimited fuel tank and has I unit of fuel initially. Along the route, there are N number of fuel stations, and the ith station is S(i) miles away from the place you leave, and F(i) unit of fuel supply. Assume the vehicle consumes 1 unit of gas for 1 mile it travels.

It is asked to find the minimum stops the car has to make before it arrives the destination.

I solved this problem by tracking the possible fuel stations the car has to stop from the very beginning. it works but it runs too slow for large number of stops. Can somebody help me to find an more efficient algorithms for it? Thanks.